# How to and retrieve , display the key and value of map<string,id> in LWC which is returning from an apex wrapper class

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, wrapper-class

**Apex method**

```java
@AuraEnabled(cacheable = true)
public static List<WrapperClass> pageResourcesFalse(String cardName){
    List<id> documentId = new List<id>();
    List<string> resourceId = new List<string>();

    map<string,list<id>> docName= new map<string,list<id>>();

    list<Document> docList = new list<Document>();

    List<CPT_Resources__c> cptRescList = [SELECT Id, Name,Is_Document__c, Documents_ID_s__c,Sequence__c, Parent_Type__c FROM CPT_Resources__c WHERE Parent_Type__c =: cardName AND Is_Document__c = false];
    System.debug(cptRescList);

    for(CPT_Resources__c cp :cptRescList){
        if(cp.Documents_ID_s__c != null){
            System.debug(cp.Documents_ID_s__c);
            documentId=cp.Documents_ID_s__c.split(',');
            docName.put(cp.name, documentId); 
            resourceId.add(cp.Id);   
        }
        System.debug('docName---' + docName);
    }
    list<WrapperClass> wrap = new list<WrapperClass>();
    docList = [Select id, Name, Folder.Name from Document where Folder.Name = 'CPT Documents'];
    System.debug('Id of Dcuments : ------' + docList);
    map<string,id> documName = new map<string,id>();
    for(String mpp : docName.keySet()){
        for(Document docL :docList){
            if(docName.get(mpp).contains(docL.id)){ 
                documName.put(docL.name,docL.id);                   
            }
        }
        System.debug('docname----' + documName);

        WrapperClass wra = new WrapperClass();
        wra.Id = resourceId;
        wra.resourceName= mpp;
        wra.docName=documName;
        wra.resourceNameWhite= mpp.deleteWhitespace();
        wrap.add(wra);       
    }
    System.debug('wrapperList: ------------'+ wrap);
    return wrap;
    //added
}
```

**Wrapper Class**

```java
public class WrapperClass{
    @AuraEnabled
    public List<string> Id {get; set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    public string resourceName{get; set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    public map<string,id> docName{get; set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    public string resourceNameWhite{get; set;}
}
```

**HTML**

```html
<template if:true={resourceListFalse}>
    <template for:each={resourceListFalse} for:item="resourceFalse">
        <div key={resourceFalse.Id} class="ac slds-p-bottom_x-small slds-p-left_x-large">
            <lightning-accordion allow-multiple-sections-open class="acClass1 slds-p-left_none" active-section-name={activeSections}>
                <lightning-accordion-section name="B" label={resourceFalse.resourceName}>

                    <a href="#">{resourceFalse.docName}</a><br/>

                </lightning-accordion-section>
            </lightning-accordion>
        </div>
    </template>
</template>
```

**JS**

```js
@track resourceListFalse = [];
@track tile = 'MiniMed™ 670G System';

connectedCallback()
{
   console.log('connectedCallBack');
   this.getPageResoursesFalse();
}


getPageResoursesFalse()
{
    pageResourcesFalse({cardName:this.tile})
    .then((result)=>{
        this.resourceListFalse = result;
       // this.resourceListFalse = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify((result)));
        console.log('result: '+JSON.stringify(this.resourceListFalse));
        
    })
    .catch((error)=> {
        console.log('error: '+error);
    })
}
```

I want to display the document name in html of lwc and want to create an url with its dynamic document id from apex and send those to lwc.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am asking that from that wrapper class I am returning a map<string,id> , I want to display the key of map in lwc

Comment: can you please also  post  your   lwc code  what  you have tried.  basically  you have to  iterate over map,   store   key in an array   and  use  template:forech to  display   that array.   please let us know  what you have attempted and where you are facing issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below logic in LWC JS file:

```js
getPageResoursesFalse()
{
    pageResourcesFalse({cardName:this.tile})
    .then((result)=>{
        let resultData = [...result];
        resultData.forEach((resourceItem)=>{
            let array = []

            Object.keys(resourceItem.docName).forEach((el) => {
              
              array.push({
                name: el,
                id: resourceItem.docName[el],
                url:
                  "https://xxxxxx.lightning.force.com/" + resourceItem.docName[el]
                  //this is org base URL
              });
              
              resourceItem.docDetails = array
            });
            
        }
        
        
        this.resourceListFalse = resultData
        
    })
    .catch((error)=> {
        console.log('error: '+error);
    })
}
```

Update the anchor tag as below:

```html
<a href={resourceFalse.docDetails.url}>{resourceFalse.docDetails.name}</a><br/>
```

Comment: Error: TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object                                                                        -------------------------------------------------------------------                                                         This error came in console

Comment: `Error: TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object ------------------------------------------------------------------- This error came in console.. @Sneh, Could you please look into this issue`

Comment: `Hi @Gaurav, It is showing Type error, can't add property docDetails, object is not extensible`

Comment: Can you replace  let resultData = [... result]   with   let resultData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify((result)));  and check if it solves.    Please also note that  @sneh  has  provided  you with idea  how to proceed  with the logic   .  It  would be hard to debug line by line issue .  Please try to solve it by following basic idea in the code.

Comment: `I want to know what is 'docDetails' here? In the UI I am not getting anything`

Comment: `In console I am getting all the things, but in the ui , neither the name nor the url is being displayed, is the line of code correct in html?`

Comment: docDetails  will be an array containing  your map key     value  and  url based  on I'd.  Please try to understand  the code written.   In html   ,  you  should  iterate over it  by using  one more template for each  inside   original template for each.   Please also check using console.log  you should be seeing all your keys  inside this variable

Comment: I got that docDetails part ,and getting all my keys in console also but when I put docDetails.name or docDetails.url in anchor tag html, I am getting nothing. If I put resourceListFalse.docDetails only, I am getting [object,object] in ui. Can you tell me the exact change I need to make in html if possible

Comment: Can you refer my previous comment  about using one more template for each and try?

Comment: <template for:each={docDetails} for:item="doc">
                        <div key={doc.id}>
                            <a href={doc.url}>{doc.name}</a><br/>
                        </div>
                    </template>                                                                                                                    I tried this, not working,

Comment: It should be resourceFalse.docDetails not docDetails and this template for each should be inside main template for each nested

Comment: Are all the others things --- for:item , div key=, and anchor tag written correctly?

Comment: Looks fine  but cannot say  until I run it myself.  If  you face any issue please try to resolve it  hope  you got it now  how to achieve it logic wise

Comment: Yeah Thanks a lot both of you. It is working fine.